# I need some help. Gstreamer. H.264 encoding + decoding + displaying. In c code

Tags: c, gstreamer, h.264

Fist of all, I have to say that I am new in Gstreamer's enviroment.

I would like to encode the source (video/x264), later to decode and finally to display. But I am doing something wrong. Can someone help me?

You can see here the code I am using:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  GMainLoop* loop;

  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *encoder, *decoder, *sink;

  gst_init(&argc, &argv);

  loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

  // initialize elements
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("audio-player");
  source = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "source");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink");
  encoder = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "encoder");
  decoder = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decoder");

  if (!pipeline || !source || !encoder || !decoder || !sink) {
    g_printerr("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // add elements to pipeline
  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, encoder, decoder, sink, NULL);

  // link elements
  gst_element_link(source,encoder); 
  gst_element_link(encoder,decoder);
  gst_element_link(decoder,sink); 
  //gst_element_link_many(source, sink, NULL);

  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  g_main_loop_run(loop);

  // cleanup
  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));
  g_main_loop_unref(loop);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Most likely you want a color space converter between decoder and sink. Perhaps ha parser between encoder and decoder too. Also make sure the profile created by the encoder is decodable by the deocder.

Comment: If I add the encoder and decoder to the pipeline I can't display the videotestsrc.